# How do I connect Ecto to CockroachDB Serverless?

Tags: database, elixir, ecto, cockroachdb, cockroachcloud

I'd like to use CockroachDB Serverless for my Ecto application. How do I specify the connection string?

I get an error like this when trying to connect.

```
[error] GenServer #PID<0.295.0> terminating
** (Postgrex.Error) FATAL 08004 (sqlserver_rejected_establishment_of_sqlconnection) codeParamsRoutingFailed: missing cluster name in connection string
    (db_connection 2.4.1) lib/db_connection/connection.ex:100: DBConnection.Connection.connect/2
```

CockroachDB Serverless says to connect by including the cluster name in the connection string, like this:

```
postgresql://username:<ENTER-PASSWORD>@free-tier.gcp-us-central1.cockroachlabs.cloud:26257/defaultdb?sslmode=verify-full&sslrootcert=$HOME/.postgresql/root.crt&options=--cluster%3Dcluster-name-1234
```

but I'm not sure how to get Ecto to create this connection string via its configuration.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that Postgrex is not able to parse all of the information from the connection URL - notable the SSL configuration. The solution is to specify the connection parameters explicitly, including the `cacertfile` SSL option. Assuming that you have downloaded your cluster's CA certificate to `priv/certs/ca-cert.crt`, you can use the following config as a template:

```
config :my_app, MyApp.Repo,
  username: "my_user",
  password: "my_password",
  database: "defaultdb",
  hostname: "free-tier.gcp-us-central1.cockroachlabs.cloud",
  port: "26257",
  ssl: true,
  ssl_opts: [
    cacertfile: Path.expand("priv/certs/ca-cert.crt"),
  ],
  parameters: [options: "--cluster=my-cluster-123"]
```

### Possible Other Issues

#### Table Locking

Since that CockroachDB also does not support the locking that Ecto/Postgrex attempts on the migration table, the `:migration_lock` config needs to be disabled as well:

```
config :my_app, MyApp.Repo,
  # ...
  migration_lock: false
```

#### Auth generator

Finally, the new `phx.gen.auth` generator defaults to using the `citext` extension for storing a user's email address in a case-insensitive manner. The line in the generated migration that executes `CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS citext` should be removed, and the column type for the `:email` field should be changed from `:citext` to `:string`.

Answer (score 4):

This configuration allows Ecto to connect to CockroachDB Serverless correctly:

```
config :myapp, MyApp.repo,
  username: "username",
  password: "xxxx",
  database: "defaultdb",
  hostname: "free-tier.gcp-us-central1.cockroachlabs.cloud",
  port: 26257,
  ssl: true,
  ssl_opts: [
    cert_pem: "foo.pem",
    key_pem:  "bar.pem"
  ],
  show_sensitive_data_on_connection_error: true,
  pool_size: 10,
  parameters: [
    options: "--cluster=cluster-name-1234"
  ]
```

Comment: Please mark this answer as correct.

Comment: This answer does not solve the problem - the configuration is invalid.

Comment: Andrew, I've marked your answer as "correct". Thanks for the update.